# Weird oh-my-zsh behavior

Tags: macos, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I am getting some weird behavior with oh-my-zsh in vim.

1. Firstly, whenever I press tab to navigate for files in options something happens like in the screenshot below:
   [image]
   Same string as the command i am writing gets appended, but it does not create any effect. Like in the screenshot, you can see that vim is written two times, but first one is actually nothing. Even when i try to delete it, it won't.
2. Secondly, when I am trying to do javac -cp , then the files won't show, means the files are actually there but pressing the tab only gives folders and not files.

Can somebody suggest a solution to solve these problems?

Comment: @shabyasachi I did find the solution for first problem (at least it works in mac). 
You need to append this line in .zshrc 
`export LC_ALL=“en_US.UTF-8”`

I am still looking for the solution of 2nd.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed my problem too. For me, javac also works on mavericks and latest oh-my-zsh.